# Insert Text Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

1. How do you enter text boxes in a google doc spread sheet?
2. In google doc excel spreadsheet, I want to skip a few spaces between words.  Google doc allows me to insert spaces, but when I am finished typing, the spaces disappear.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per Question post. Also, there's not enough information here for us to really answer either question. Can you [edit] your question to provide more detail?

Answer (score 2):

1. Not sure if this is what you require, but you can do the following: Insert > Drawing... > Click Text Box (the button with the T icon) > type the text and format the box as required > Save & Close
2. You can directly enter non-breaking spaces on a Windows machine by typing Alt+255, and a Mac OS by Opt+Space. I don't know any way of directly entering non-breaking spaces on Linux (that's not to say there isn't a way). However, you can achieve non-breaking spaces independent of OS via formula:

`="There are five spaces between here"&REPT(CHAR(160);5)&"and here."`